# Live Xojo built web app examples + getting started in Xojo

Tags: xojo

I'm brand new to Xojo and I intend on learning to build web apps for my organisation in Xojo and have a Java element to it (as that is my background) i.e. essentially for the application I'll be developing some of the behind the scenes work will be done in Java.

In saying this I was kindly asking someone direct me towards live examples of Xojo web apps (commecrical or non-commerical). It would be nice to see the outcomes of of Xojo web app development. Below are some examples from the following forum link - [Xojo web app examples](https://forum.xojo.com/2015-web-apps-examples/0):

- [Xojo web app example 1](http://lightingapps.de/)
- [Xojo web app example 2](http://www.ezmeter.com/cgi-bin/catalog/metercatalog.cgi)
- [Xojo web app example 3](http://www.hangarbox.de/)

In addition I would like to know apart from the textbook (http://xojo.com/learn/), the resources link ([Xojo resources](http://xojo.com/resources/)) and youtube videos ([Xojo YouTube videos](https://www.youtube.com/user/goxojo/videos?sort=da&view=0&flow=list)) are there any other well laid out beginner tutorials out there.

I look forward to using Xojo to build solid web apps.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

Alex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest, the Xojo Forums https://forum.xojo.com are by far the best place to ask Xojo questions.  The community is very helpful and all forum posts 100% Xojo related.  So this is not the best venue for those.

My company has over 42 hours of Xojo and Real Studio training video at http://xojo.bkeeney.com/XojoTraining/.  We are about ready to start a full series on web apps but that will be a month before it's complete.

We also offer one-on-one training and consulting services.  Contact us at http://www.bkeeney.com.  We have quite a few clients that come to us for example code so that they can learn a specific technique and incorporate our code into their own project.

I know there are other resources but I've not kept up with them.  Again, the best place to ask is the Xojo Forum.

Comment: you have posted information about your courses in a lot of places, yet all these links are dead. A responsible person would at least put up a placeholder at that location saying you no longer provide those courses, or you've given up, or "look over at this address, the courses are now here!" But in any case, I keep stumbling across your links and they are dead. (while writing this, I decided to track you down, I will send an email) #notstalking! :)